# Forward my domain name to my blog

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, blogspot

I had my domain listed in blogspot(http://www.example.blogspot.in) and recently I have purchased a domain name (example.com) and routed this domain to my blog. Now when I open http://www.example.com , my blog opens but if I simply browse http://example.com , then blog doesnot open. How can I make the url http://example.com to forward to my domain name ?

Comment: I think you're a bit off topic here.

Comment: what off topic?? This question is under appropriate tags.

Comment: You're looking to do a "naked domain redirect", the specifics of which depend on how you've set up your domain — but that's what you should search for in order to learn more.

Comment: This is just spam, if it was a serious question it would use example.com

Comment: Ok , I am changing domain name with example.com.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't either added A name records or you haven't checked the box in Blogger Settings. The second one is what many of the users miss.

Dhiraj 
AllBloggerTricks.com

Comment: I have checked the check box now. Will it take some time to have effect as it is not working even now.